# How can I save the output of tail to my clipboard or somewhere on a SSH session where there is only a unidirectional connection and server is limited?

Tags: linux, scp, clipboard, tail

I have to report some logs from some of the servers in our infrastructure which I have limited permissions on. Every time I copy 1000 lines of logs and paste it into Slack, I can't do scp from the server to my local computer. I can only scp from my local and grab a file and paste it in a directory on my laptop. I cannot install any packages on this server as I have no permission like that.

The command I'm using is this:

```
tail -n 1000 ./mylogfile.log
```

My process is this:

1. SSH into server
2. Run that tail command
3. Copy 1000 lines of code
4. Paste and report it in Slack

What I want to achieve:

1. Run that command
2. Somehow get that log file on my local system as a file or in my clipboard (preferred), which is hard because of limitations I have

My limitations are:

1. I can only see this server through VPN, the server can't see me, and I can't do SCP from the server.
2. I can't install any new packages

In summary, I want to get that 1000 lines of log through an easy clean way without copying despite the limitations I have.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: `tail /var/log/your.log | tee /tmp/tail.log` ... Please, writing a question in the topic and not writing or articulating it in the actual question is not so cool, please take your time and rewrite your question. Also, your question is not very precise. That's why I'm giving you this lazy answer.

Comment: @paladin I'm very sorry for the poorly written question, I tried my best to add more details and be more clear, I'm not a native English speaker so I'm trying my best, Thank you.

Comment: Does `ssh user@server 'tail -n 1000 ./mylogfile.log' > ./localfile` solve "get that log file on my local system as a file"?

Comment: [Slack lets you email things to it](https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack). You can set up a channel and any emails sent to a specific address appear as messages in that channel. That might be the best workaround for you: just run your command and pass it through `mail` to send to the slack email. Would that work for you or do you absolutely need to copy/paste?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski This solves my problem, but is there a flag that would make it not exit after executing the command?

Comment: @Ilgar: What would the command be supposed to do, if it did not exit?